# I am oblivious to my error in my SQL query. Please correct it for me. Tell me why its wrong?

Tags: mysql

I am oblivious to my error in my SQL query. Please correct it for me. Tell me why it's wrong.

I am ultimately trying to create a trigger that will auto-insert avgs into columns each time a row is inserted using php. But I just can't seem to get the hang of how a query is organized.

```
Update db.tablename1 
set AvgM2toM1 = (select avg(M2toM1) FROM tablename1 ORDER BY Desc Limit 0, 5) where ID = Max(ID)
```

I'm still getting an error. Any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have missed `FROM tablename` in the subquery

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a FROM clause in your sub query.

Where you have

```
AbgM2toM1 = (select avg(M2toM1)
```

You need to follow that with a FROM clause.

Regards,
Ralfe

Comment: Hey Ralfe, i am still missing something. Do you have any more ideas

Comment: Hi, yes, you also made a mistake with the ORDER BY. You need to have a field name directly between "ORDER BY" and "Desc".

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(M2toM1) from table_name
```

from is missing in your subquery